# Can I use PrimeFaces push with just PrimeFaces and Extensions jars?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions, primefaces-push

I don't understand how to use PrimeFaces Push when I have PrimeFaces 5.1 jar and PrimeFaces Extensions 2.1.0 in my classpath.

Are there any other jar **dependencies** that I need to take care of?

Could you please provide me the brief clarification on this, please?

Comment: Please start by reading the PrimeFaces documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Primefaces 5.1 documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf) page 12

[image]

After that you need to read ***entire chapter 9***. Only after reading that and checking tutorials ask your next question. Please read twice if time permits